# A triple symbolic integral in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I am trying to evaluate:

```
syms a theta r z real
int(int(int(r,z,-sqrt(a^2-r^2),sqrt(a^2-r^2)),...
    r,0,a*cos(theta)),theta,0,pi)
```

Without success.

```
Warning: Explicit integral could not be found. 
Warning: Explicit integral could not be found. 

ans =

int((2*(a^2)^(3/2))/3 - (2*(a^2*sin(theta)^2)^(3/2))/3, theta == 0..pi)
```

Am I doing something wrong, or is this type of integral not possible in Matlab?

To answer some questions in the comments, here is the hand written solution. Unfortunately, MathJax is not available in Stackoverflow, so I've included it in a photo. I've shortcutted the steps so that the photo wasn't too large.

[image]

And then, here is the Mathematica code that produced the same answer.

[image]

Comment: I do not get error message running your code, using Matlab20014b.

Comment: I just tried it in 2013b, and it didn't give a closed form solution.

Comment: Are you sure this integral has an analytical solution? I mean one that does not require approximations?

Comment: @patrik: Yes, this computes the volume bounded by the cylinder r = a cos(theta) that lies inside the sphere of radius a. I am using: MATLAB Version: 8.1.0.604 (R2013a).

Comment: @David Did you read my answer? If the only problem is that you cannot solve the integral you could try to find another parametrisation. It this is possible it may even be worth an hour or two of thinking, comparing with the alternative. I am not 100% sure but at least 99% that you have managed to create an elliptic integral.

Comment: Thinking about it, this may not be covered by this forum, but if you want you can upload an image of the problem. I have a little trouble catching it. I feel that the cylinder shuold have a fixed radius, but I may not get the point here

Comment: @David I do not want to be rude or so, but you should try to answer the comments so that I know that you are still interested in solving the problem, otherwise your question will get flagged. The answer does explain why you get the warning and if you want an answer to why the integral becomes as it does you need to provide more information.

Comment: Here is the region, drawn using a=1: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/65232/draw-a-region-bound-by-a-sphere-and-a-cylinder

Comment: @David I see. I think that your profile in r is a bit doubtful. That one looks more like the number 8. One more question here. Is the cylinder centered? In that case try to set the r limit to `sqrt(a^2-z^2)`,which is the radius of the cylinder as a function of z. This makes the intgral angle independent. Then keep the intgrator as the function r. If the integral is not centered you need the angle dependence, but you need to adjust it so that it is correct. Anyway, always try to keep r as a function of angle and z and set the upper limits of z to +-sqrt(a^2-roCyl^2).

Comment: You can also try math stack exchange and try to get better help on how to intgrate the function.

Comment: Ok sorry, I will flag this question with the reasons, the user is inactive and does not seem to have analyzed the question enough for a constructive discussion, the question does not belong to this forum. Since you have not commented the elliptic integral track I assume that you have not investigated it. This since consider it wrong with the assumptions that the question is possible to solve in a simple way and that your approach is correct. This is not a good assumption at this point since that assumes everyone is wrong including matlab and wolframAlpha.

Comment: I do not write this to anyway disencourage you to continue to ask questions on stack overflow, but give feedback on answers, comments and so on. To be able to give help I need to know why you agree or disagree and further explain the problem if you do not get the answers that you expect.

Comment: @patrik: I've added my hand solution to my question and then I used Mathematica to check my answer. Lots to do right now teaching, so I'll just have to wait until I can update to the latest version of Matlab, which the first comment above said was able to handle the integration.

Comment: @David I see, matlab does actually seem to have som problems simplifying the expression `(sin(theta)^2)^(3/2)`. Sorry, it seems that I did a miscalculation and this seems to be the problem. I will edit my answer for this question. And regarding matlab 2014b: it does not give an error or warning, but it does not evaluate the intgral either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see, matlab does actually seem to have som problems simplifying the expression (sin(theta)^2)^(3/2). This causes trouble in the final integral. And regarding matlab 2014b: it does not give an error or warning, but it does not evaluate the intgral either.

Matlab 2014b:

int( (sin(theta)^2)^(3/2), theta, 0, pi)

ans =

int((sin(theta)^2)^(3/2), theta, 0, pi)